# workflow is not working as expected in specific criteria

Tags: apex, soql, community, email, workflow

i got a requirement to send an email to specific person in email field whenever any opportunity is created when an lead is converted.so i write a formula like

For reference:
[image]

But if select **1.Created** in criteria it is not working.

If i select 3.Criteria it is working

And **Team Lead Mail** field is updated based on a field in opportunity through process builder.

what i have to do if i want to this work in !.criteria

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that when you say `1.Created` and `3.Criteria` you're talking about the evaluation criteria `Created` and `Created, and every time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`? Is the Opportunity record type set when you convert a lead, or is that taken care of in a trigger or workflow rule?

Comment: Ya you are right.But i don't have any record type for opportunity.I updated the email field called team lead mail based on opportunity owner @Derek F

Comment: Ah, I misread the rule criteria (I thought Opportunity's `Type` field label meant it was a recordtype, but that is not the case). Your comment does shine a light on what is going on. I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

True to its name, the `Created` workflow evaluation setting only runs when a record is inserted. If your record doesn't meet the rule criteria by the time the workflow rule is evaluated, you've missed your chance.

If you are manually updating your target fields after they are inserted (or via workflow field update), then it should come as no surprise why a Workflow rule set to evaluate only when a record is created isn't being run (because that record has already been created, and you are now updating that previously created record.)

You can change fields in a `Before Insert` trigger on `Opportunity` to set your two fields to meet your workflow's rule criteria, and the workflow rule will still run.

I'm not so sure if it'll work if you have an `After Insert` `Opportunity` trigger that then calls a `Before Update` `Opportunity` trigger. Technically, it's in the same transaction as the insert, and would end up being run before workflow rules are evaluated. I'm afraid I don't have time to test if this works right now.

**+edit:**

According to comments, you are accomplishing this update (of team lead email) via Process Builder. I don't have much experience with processes, but I think I've read enough to help out here.

If you take a look at the [Salesforce Order of Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), Processes (built via Process Builder) run after triggers and after workflow rules.

That means that your update to the field occurs too late for a workflow rule, that only runs on record creation, to be able to use it. My understanding is that a process field update will cause triggers to fire again, but at that point it is no longer considered running on record creation, but rather on an update of the record (this explains why changing the evaluation criteria to `Created, and every time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria` works).

Your options to work around this are

- stop using process builder, and do this field update in a `Before Insert` trigger
- remove the workflow rule you currently have and make it part of your
  process. Create a flow to send your email alert, and execute your flow as an immediate action in your process

Comment: Hey thanks but i my scenario team lead mail field is updated based on opportunity owner based on process builder.@Derek F

Comment: @Pavantej That's some important information that should be included in your question.